# show per column the value of each date_sub

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I want to display the sales per month of the itemcode in one query. But the only thing I can do right now is get the total of it. Im using date_sub.

```
select p.itemcode, sa.quantity
from sales sa join product p on p.itemcode = sa.itemcode
where DATE >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) and sa.quantity < 50
group by p.itemcode
```

The query shown above shows this output:

```
Itemcode        quantity
694                48
7891               45
B-04.020.12405     48
B-04.020.12407     49
```

The output that i want to show is:

```
Itemcode          1   2   3    4   5   6
694               3   10  1    20  1   0 
7891              3   10  1    20  1   0 
B-04.020.12405    0   0   0    0   3   45
B-04.020.12407    3   10  1    20  1   0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following query uses the CASE statement to check for the different ages and add the quantity accordingly:

```
select p.itemcode, 
SUM(
    CASE WHEN DATE >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) THEN sa.quantity ELSE 0 
)  1,
SUM(
    CASE WHEN DATE >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND DATE < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) THEN sa.quantity ELSE 0 
)  2,
SUM(
    CASE WHEN DATE >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AND DATE < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH) THEN sa.quantity ELSE 0 
)  3,
SUM(
    CASE WHEN DATE >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 4 MONTH) AND DATE < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) THEN sa.quantity ELSE 0 
)  4,
SUM(
    CASE WHEN DATE >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 MONTH) AND DATE < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 4 MONTH) THEN sa.quantity ELSE 0 
)  5,
SUM(
    CASE WHEN DATE >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND DATE < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 MONTH) THEN sa.quantity ELSE 0 
)  6
from sales sa join product p on p.itemcode = sa.itemcode
where DATE >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) and sa.quantity < 50
group by p.itemcode;
```